# Efficiency of loading nested data

Tags: swift, realm

I have been experimenting with hierarchical datasets in Realm-Swift, specifically infinitely nested nodes (trees). To be honest, I am not sure how to measure the performance, efficiency, or the impact a dataset has when loading a node.

Consider a data structure like this:

```
Item (Root):
    - Children[]:
        + Item
        - Item
            - Children[]:
                + Item
                + Item
            - CreatedOn
        + Item
        + Item
        + Item
        - Item
            - Children[]:
                + Item
                + Item
                + Item
                + Item
            - CreatedOn
        + Item
        + Item
        + Item
    - CreatedOn
```

Assuming there are about 1 million nodes, these are some questions I have:

1. I understand that realm supports lazy loading of properties. So if I were to query for the root node alone all 1 million entries won't be loaded right?
2. Suppose the root node itself has 100k children if I were to access the children of the root node with `item.Children` Would realm load all nodes in the children list? Or is it possible to page through them?
3. Of course, we don't want all 1 million entries in memory is there any support for weak references? How does one manage a scenario like this?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are correct, the entries would not all be loaded. Relationships between Realm objects are represented as pointers within the underlying data structure, meaning that you should be able to create arbitrarily complex trees of objects without running into any issue loading any single object.
2. The Realm collection types do not eagerly load the objects they represent into memory. Objects themselves are lightweight wrappers around accessors directly into the underlying data structure, which is itself a portion of the on-disk (or in-memory) file `mmap`ed into the process's address space. Note that there are some subtleties to memory management: since Realm is an MVCC database and since the lifetime of a given snapshot of the database is linked to the lifetimes of the objects referencing that snapshot, carelessly written code may needlessly force Realm to keep multiple snapshots of the database in memory simultaneously, causing memory usage and file sizes to grow.
3. Realm Swift doesn't have any notion of weak references, but because of the two points above it shouldn't need them.

Our article, [Realm Threading Deep Dive](https://news.realm.io/news/threading-deep-dive/), provides an overview of how Realm works (check out the *Underpinnings of Realm* section), and might be of interest to you as well.